# IB_designable externally

Tags: ios8, interface-builder, ibdesignable

Ive been looking into IB_designable and it is a really awesome feature.  However, one issue that I have with it is that for each view, I have to subclasses a UIView.  And within that Subclass I have to specify the UI elements inside the initWithCoder: method and prepareForInterfaceBuilder:

However, I want to be able to specify the UI Elements OUTSIDE of the class.

I want to make a UIView subclass that has a public property of which I can set from the outside and see in Inter face builder.

Is this possible?

UPDATE:

I am aware of IBInspectible.  This makes the property available in the Attributes inspector.  This is not what I mean by external.

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface DesignableLabel : UILabel
@end
@implementation DesignableLabel 
@end

@interface SomeClass : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet DesignableLabel *DL;
}
@end
@interface SomeClass
- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {
    DL.text = @"Hello World"
}
@end
```

DesignableLable is a subclass of UILabel.  UILabels have a text property.  I want SomeClass to somehow set that property.  Normally if I do that and run the app, it should show the string.  However, to save myself the trouble of running the app, I want it to show up in Interface builder so I can see its value as I type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question so that other people may benefit.  You can use User Defined Runtime Attributes to call a category method to set your IB_Designable object from the outside.

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface DesignableLabel : UILabel
@end

@implementation DesignableLabel 
@end

@implementation DesignableLabel (Runtime_TheTextYouWant)
    - (void)setTheText:(BOOL)b {
        if (!b) return;
        self.text = "The text you want";
    }
@end

@implementation DesignableLabel (Runtime_SayHelloToMyLittleFriend)
    - (void)setMyLittleFriend:(BOOL)b {
        if (!b) return;
        self.text = "Say hello to my little friend";
    }
@end
```

I have created two categories for my DesignableLabel.  Now if I place two UILabels into my ViewController in storyboard, and subclass both UILabel's to DesignableLabel, then for the first UILabel I can use the user defined runtime attribute by calling the key path

```
theText
```

With the type of boolean and set the check mark.  Then that particular DesignableLabel Object will have the text specified in the setTheText: category method.

Similarly, for the second DesignableLabel object, you would use the user defined runtime attribute by calling the key path

```
myLittleFriend
```

Notice that the key path does not use the word "set" and it lower cases the first word.  setMyLittleFriend: becomes myLittleFriend.

In conclusion, this saves you from having to make a subclass for EACH IB_DESIGNABLE object.

Answer (score 0):

The public property you want to set externally (using your public API) has to be marked with the `IBInspectable` keyword. 
Ex:

```
 @property (readwrite) IBInspectable BOOL activityIndicatorOn;
```

You can find more info about this keyword on [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014224-CH41-SW1).

Comment: That talks about adding a property to the Attributes inspector.  That isn't really what I am asking... Please see my update.  Hopefully it clarifies things...